# I have similar triangles sharing a common point, with common tangents. Some values are given.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

From the following, I can come up with a host of equations, given the triangles are similar, but I am struggling to solve 3 unknowns in 3 equations, with the intention of ultimately finding x.
[image: Textbook excerpt]

This is a text book question, in a section about similar triangles.

Let circle at centre B have radius $r_2$
Let circle at centre E have radius $r_1$

$\triangle ABC \sim \triangle AED \sim \triangle EBF$  (AAA)

1. $\frac{AE}{AD}=\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{EB}{EF}$

$\frac{x+r_1}{5} = \frac{x+2r_1+r_2}{5+12.8}= \frac{r_1+r_2}{12.8}$

2. Pythagoras on $\triangle$ABC $(x+2r_1+r_2)^2=(5+12.8)^2+(r_2)^2$
3. Pythagoras on $\triangle$AED $(x+r_1)^2=(5)^2+(r_1)^2$
4. Pythagoras on $\triangle$EBF $(r_1+r_2)^2=(12.8)^2+(r_2-r_1)^2$

And this is the part where it gets tricky for me. When I try to solve 3 unknowns in 3 equations, I start to get confused about where to start.

I'll show you what I would try, and if you could point me in the right direction, that will be helpful.

From 4): $(r_1+r_2)^2=(12.8)^2+(r_2-r_1)^2$
$r_1+2r_1r_2+r_2^2 = (12.8)^2 + r_2^2-2r_2r_1+r_1^2$
$4r_1r_2=12.8^2$
$r_1=\frac{40.96}{r_2}$ (5)

I get to this point and am not sure if I'm heading in the right direction. My text book uses elimination method to solve for 3 unknowns, but I can't identify a way to eliminate any of those equations, and I've tried substitution method but it ends up messy, and incorrect.

Comment: One can skip $x+2r_1+r_2$ part because it does not add anything. One can use $(x+r_1)^2=5^2+r_1^2$ to express $r_1$ in terms of $x$, then use $(r_1+r_2)^2=(12.8)^2+(r_2-r_1)^2$ to express $r_2$ in terms of $x$,  then put them into equation $\frac{x+r_1}{5}=\frac{r_1+r_2}{12.8}$ and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

After @ivan-kaznacheyeu guided me, I put together some more information and got the answer as shown here:

$\frac{BC}{ED}$=$\frac{CA}{DA}$
=$\frac{r_2}{r_1}$ = $\frac{17.8}{5}$

From 5) $r_2=\frac{17.8r_1}{5}$

$5r_2=17.8(\frac{40.96}{r_2})$

$\frac{(5r_2)^2}{5}=\frac{729.088}{5}$

$r_2=\sqrt{145.8176}$

$r_2=12.08$ (2 d.p)

$r_1=\frac{40.96}{12.08}$

$r_1=3.39$

From 1):
$\frac{x+r_1}{5}=\frac{x+2r_1}{17.8}$

$\frac{x+3.39}{5}=$$\frac{x+2(3.39)+12.08}{17.8}$

$17.8x+60.342=5x+33.9+60.4$

$\frac{12.8x}{12.8}=\frac{33.96}{12.8}$

$x=2.65$

Thanks for all your help guys.